# error with nested if condition on a batch script that sets a variable that disappears when removing it

Tags: batch-file, if-statement

i have a batch script like this:

```
@echo off
setlocal

some commands to set variable %equal%

if %equal%==no (
    some commands to set variable %equall% (including a call to a separate batch file)
    if %equall%==no (
        other commands (including a call to a separate batch file)
    )
) else (
    echo nothing new
)

endlocal
exit /b
```

But i getting this error (translated from spanish, so it can be innacurate): `"(" was not expected at this moment` on the first if sentence.

However, if i remove the inner if condition, it runs fine....

What am i missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you've got a [delayed expansion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30284028/2152082) problem. The variable `equall` gets defined inside a code block, so `%equall%` is still not defined. That makes your line

```
if %equall%==no (
```

to be parsed as

```
if ==no (
```

which leads to the mentioned error `"(" is unexpected at this time"`

To correct it, *enable* delayed expansion with the `setlocal enabledelayedexpansion` command and *use* delayed expansion with `!` syntax instead of `%` syntax:

```
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
if 1==1 (
  set "var=hello"
  echo !var!
)
```

Also you should get used to use a better syntax with `if` (quoting both sides of the comparison):

```
if "%var%" == "value" ...
```

(or with delayed expansion: `if "!var!% == "value"`) Even if the variable is empty, this gets parsed as:

```
if "" == "value" ...
```

which is perfectly valid syntax.

Comment: Thankz a lot!. How do i call a for loop variable (%%i) in delayed extension?

Comment: loop variables (`%%i`) can't be delayed. Its just `%%i`

Answer (score 0):

I used a workaround, that is to send everything inside the outer if to a label:

```
@echo off
setlocal

some commands to set variable %equal%

if %equal%==no (
    goto :label
) else (
    echo nothing new
)

endlocal
exit /b

:label
some commands to set variable %equall% (including a call to a separate batch file)
if %equall%==no (
    other commands (including a call to a separate batch file)
)
```